# How to do alias in mixpanel on already signedup users?

Tags: mixpanel

I wasn't using the alias initially in my app, theres about some 100 users now signed up and events are recorded. Now I would want to do alias on the existing users with some identity string.

Answer (score 0):

For additional context, when the Mixpanel alias method is called, behind the scenes, an event named '$create_alias' is triggered to establish the mapping between your internal uuid and the Mixpanel anonymous distinct_id.  To alias users that have already signed up, you could send a '$create_alias' event to the /track API for each user that you would like to alias.  You could even batch send these events in batches of up to 50. Further documentation can be found here: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http#distinct-id-alias

As a note, this event will not count towards your monthly quota or appear in your Mixpanel project!